# How to only filter an item of each type?

Tags: javascript

Given an array of objects such as

```
[
  {name: "john", power: 1},
  {name: "john", power: 129391},
  {name: "john", power: 91},
  {name: "philip", power: 33},
  {name: "philip", power: 883},
  {name: "philip", power: 3112333},
]
```

I'd like to get only one item of each `name` - the item with the most `power`. The result would be:

```
  {name: "john", power: 129391},
  {name: "philip", power: 3112333},
```

I just don't know how to filter one of each. I am able to filter items with the same name but not with different names
`items.filter(item => item.name === 'john')`

One thing I thought was to compare the items to the items that already are in the resulting array but haven't found a way to access the resulting array.

Comment: You'll probably have to filter by each individual name at some point anyway, because you need all the power values for one user first, before you can determine what the maximum among those is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traverse the first array and accumulate the unique keys you want to keep in another array. Then traverse again, doing the checks you want on a per unique key basis (in this key comparing `power`):

```js
let input = [
  { name: "john", power: 1 },
  { name: "john", power: 129391 },
  { name: "john", power: 91 },
  { name: "philip", power: 33 },
  { name: "philip", power: 883 },
  { name: "philip", power: 3112333 },
];

let uniqueKeys = input
  .map((e) => e.name)
  .filter((key, i) => input.findIndex((e) => e.name === key) === i);

let output = uniqueKeys.map(
  (key) =>
    input
      .filter((e) => e.name === key)
      .sort((entryA, entryB) => entryB.power - entryA.power)[0]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reduce

```js
const data = [
  {name: "john", power: 1},
  {name: "john", power: 129391},
  {name: "john", power: 91},
  {name: "philip", power: 33},
  {name: "philip", power: 883},
  {name: "philip", power: 3112333},
]

const powerUsersObj = data.reduce((acc,cur) => {
  acc[cur.name] = acc[cur.name] ? Math.max(acc[cur.name],cur.power) : cur.power
  return acc
},{})
console.log(powerUsersObj)

const powerUsersArr = Object.entries(powerUsersObj).map(entry => ({name:entry[0],power:entry[1]}))
console.log(powerUsersArr)
```

Comment: I love this process

Comment: It can likely be shortened

Answer (score 0):

Use some dictionary or map to keep track of old selections, and replace items as necessary while iterating.

```js
var arr = [
  {name: "john", power: 1},
  {name: "john", power: 129391},
  {name: "john", power: 91},
  {name: "philip", power: 33},
  {name: "philip", power: 883},
  {name: "philip", power: 3112333},
]
var selectedItems = {}
arr.forEach(item => {
    const key = item.name;
    if(selectedItems[key] && selectedItems[key].power < item.power) {
        selectedItems[key] = item
    } else if(!selectedItems[key]) {
        selectedItems[key] = item
    }
});
console.log(Object.values(selectedItems))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use reduce function

```js
const  table = [
  {name: "john", power: 1},
  {name: "john", power: 129391},
  {name: "john", power: 91},
  {name: "philip", power: 33},
  {name: "philip", power: 883},
  {name: "philip", power: 3112333},
]

 const result = [...table.reduce((r, o) => {
    const key = o.name;
    const item = r.get(key) || Object.assign({ name: o.name }, {power: 0});
    item.power = o.power>item.power? o.power: item.power;
    return r.set(key, item);
  }, new Map).values()]
        
        

console.log(result);
```